# How to get the inserted values by Cassandra 3. X trigger?

Tags: java, triggers, cassandra

How can I get every column value for an inserted row in Cassandara 3.X by using a trigger.
I use this implementation.

```
@Override
public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition prtn) {
}
```

I've searched a lot and I only get the value of the inserted partition key in a string but I need all inserted values.